# Generics and ArrayList

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

How can I access the methods in the Students class. When I print myList it uses the toString in the students class, I'm not sure how to access the other methods. Is that even possible?

PS I already have the try and catch in my program, I just didn't post here to make the code shorter.

```
public class DatabaseAccess <T> {
    public T[] database;
    public ArrayList<T>myList = new ArrayList<T>();
    public ArrayList<T> testlist = new ArrayList<T>();
    public void userInterface(){
    int count = 1;
        for (T i : myList){ 
            System.out.println(count++ + ": " + i);     
        }
    }
    public void readDatabase(){
        try {
                ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("grocery.bin"));
                database = (T[]) in.readObject();
                    for (int i = 0; i < database.length; i++){
                        myList.add(database[i]);    
                }
                myList.add((T) "\n");
                myList.add((T)  "\tStudents:");
                ObjectInputStream in1 = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("students.bin"));
                database = (T[]) in1.readObject();
                    for (int i = 0; i < database.length; i++){
                         myList.add(database[i]);
                    }
    }
}



     public class Student implements Serializable, Comparable{
     private String name, id, address;
     private double gpa;

     public Student(String name, String id, double gpa){
         this.name = name;
         this.id = id;
         this.gpa = gpa;
     }
     public int compareTo(Object object){
         Student student = (Student ) object;
         if(this.gpa < student.getGpa())
              return -1;
         else
               if(this.gpa > student.getGpa())
            return 1;
               else
                    return 0;
     }
     public String getName(){ return name;}
     public String getId(){ return id;}
     public double getGpa(){ return gpa;}
     public String toString(){ return (String.format("%16s%10.4s%8s", name, id, gpa));}
}
```

Comment: There's a lot of casting going on here, at least one or two I see that don't need to be taking place, and one I think is missing.  What are you trying to accomplish? If there are any stacks, what are they?  Can you reproduce this problem with a hard-coded piece of input as opposed to some file (it would make figuring this out a **lot** faster)?

Comment: I'm trying to access the getMeethods in the Student class, i'm not sure how. and what missing casting is there? and what casting don't i need?

Comment: It looks like `T`is always a `String`, which makes think you do not need the type parameter at all. Otherwise your code casting Strings to `T` is going to cause some heap pollution in your lists and probably make your code fail at run time.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo What heap pollution? Casts to a generic type is equivalent to casts to the raw type, which in the OP's case is `Object` (unless they implement my suggestion of using `DatabaseAccess<T extends Student>`, in which case `T`'s raw type is `Student`).

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young If you add a String to a list of T where T that is supposed to be a Student and then you try to iterate over the list assuming they are students. Wouldn't it fail?

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo Of course it'd fail, but not at the point in the code that you'd expect.

Comment: so how can i access it? there's another class that is similar to Students, so i can't make it extend one and not the other.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Well, your questions was "what heap pollution?". I think it would fail exactly where I would have expected. My point simply was that this could be the cause of a problem not evident in this code and it is certainly introducing pollution into a list allegedly of type T at compile time. At runtime we could violate that due to type erasure, which would precisely be the pollution in question and my original point.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo I think you and I mean completely different things by "heap pollution". I think you're talking about the ability to put non-`T` objects into a `List<T>`. When I say "heap pollution", I mean that objects are unnecessarily created.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Well, I meant it in the context defined by the [JLS-4.12.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.2): "It is possible that a variable of a parameterized type will refer to an object that is not of that parameterized type. This situation is known as heap pollution."

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo Point taken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean within DatabaseAccess, in theory, you don't.

Now, you COULD use something like the following, but it is a horrible idea and absolutely reeks of bad design (no offense meant - I just don't want to give the impression that this code is at all okay or that you should use it - just that it is technically possible):

```
 for (T t : myList) {
    if (t instanceof Student) {
      Student student = (Student) t;
      student.getGpa();
    } else if (t instanceof Food) {
      ...
    }
 }
```

As far as DatabaseAccess is concerned, it's not a Student.  It's a random object of type T which we know basically nothing about.  If you can't create a common interface between the Student and Food to do what you want, you have to ask yourself why this DatabaseAccess needs to know the specifics of the classes and figure out what the design should really look like to separate things more sanely.

Are you doing some custom printing?   Maybe the formatting should be done within the Student/Food class.

Are you, e.g. processing user input and manipulating data from the objects in the database?  Separate the concerns of database access and data manipulation.  Changing a GPA shouldn't necessarily require you to know whether the data is being stored in an ObjectOutputStream or an Oracle Database.  So, have the DatabaseAccess deal with the database, and define some other class that works with a `DatabaseAccess<Student>` through some defined interface, and have that handle the Student-specific manipulation.

Without knowing precisely what you're trying to do, it's hard to give solid advice beyond: if you think you need to do what you're asking, you might want to step back and think if there might be a better way to approach the problem so that you don't.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be able to access `Student` methods from `T` instances within your `DatabaseAccess` class, you must constraint `T`'s type to be subclasses of `Student`:

```
public class DatabaseAccess<T extends Student> {
    // ...
}
```

By the way, if you make your `Student` class implement `Comparable<Student>` instead of the raw `Comparable`, your `compareTo` method would be easier to write.

Comment: can i make it extend two classes? because there are two classes i need to access the methods in. Students and Food class that is similar to students.

Comment: Can you make `Student` and `Food` implement the same interface, with all the methods you need to use? Then just use that interface in `T`'s bound.